# error messages in BOOST's has_binary_operator.hpp on OSX 10.9 Xcode6

Tags: c++, macos, boost

So, I built boost with the following [script](https://gist.github.com/catnapgames/8912307) conveniently posted by [toma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35440/toma)

and it compiles and I can add the respective frameworks in Xcode6 to my iOS target and my OSX target.

It runs properly on iOS, but when I try compiling on OSX I get errors in has_binary_operator.hpp in the following lines:

```
template < typename Lhs, typename Rhs >
struct operator_exists {
   static ::boost::type_traits::yes_type check(has_operator); // this version is preferred when operator exists
   static ::boost::type_traits::no_type check(no_operator); // this version is used otherwise

   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = (sizeof(check(((make<Lhs>() BOOST_TT_TRAIT_OP make<Rhs>()),make<has_operator>())))==sizeof(::boost::type_traits::yes_type)));
};
```

Error messages:
.../boost.framework/Headers/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:155:42: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
.../boost.framework/Headers/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:156:41: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

PS: My stdlib is libc++ and I want to use C++11 and Clang in both iOS and MacOSX. I mean it works perfectly for iOS, so why is it not working with the MacOSX target?!?

Quickfix:
Undefining 'check' seems to solve the error, as this seems to be a keyword reserved on MacOSX. Still it seems a weird solution to just undefine an OSX keyword, wouldn't this cause problems later?

```
#undef check
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is not a keyword, but an unfortunately named macro in a file supplied by Apple.

This has been an ongoing problem for boost (and other library vendors) for many years.

The header file `<AssertMacros.h>` is where this macros is defined.

See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2115 for some history on this.

The latest version of this file (that Apple ships with the 10.9 SDK) contains the following text:

- Prior to Mac OS X 10.6 the macro names used in this file conflicted with some
- user code, including libraries in boost and the proposed C++ standards efforts,
- and there was no way for a client of this header to resolve this conflict. Because
- of this, most of the macros have been changed so that they are prefixed with
- __ and contain at least one capital letter, which should alleviate the current
- and future conflicts.  However, to allow current sources to continue to compile,
- compatibility macros are defined at the end with the old names.  A tops script
- at the end of this file will convert all of the old macro names used in a directory
- to the new names.  Clients are recommended to migrate over to these new macros as
- they update their sources because a future release of Mac OS X will remove the
- old macro definitions ( without the double-underscore prefix ).  Clients who
- want to compile without the old macro definitions can define the macro
- __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES to 0 before this file is
- included.

So, you could add `-D__ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0` to your build commands to fix this problem.

Alternately, you could get a newer version of boost, where those calls have been renamed from `check` to `s_check`.

Comment: thank you, I added the makro to "Other C++ Flags" under Build Settings and it still works after deleting the "uncheck" line. 
Don't want to recompile a newer boost (I use 1.55 currently), it took long enough to get one working for both iOS and OSX..